# Changing background color of switch label with checkbox type?

Tags: css, materialize

So I am using materializecss framework for my website and I tried adding a as seen [here](http://materializecss.com/forms.html#switches). But I am having trouble with changing the color of activated switch. It uses complicated CSS, at least for me.

```
.switch label input[type=checkbox]:checked + .lever {
  background-color: #84c7c1;
}
```

For example as seen here you can see this is the default CSS which makes the background of the switch cyan. And I cant get it to change by using a id.
I tried doing it like this:

```
.switch label input[type=checkbox]#profile-switch:checked + .lever#profile-switch {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

But it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Please post the HTML structure that you're trying to use with your updated example so we can help troubleshoot properly.

Comment: When you have an element with an id, like `#profile-switch`, there is no point having a rule look like this, `.switch label input[type=checkbox]#profile-switch`, you can cut it down to its id only, like this `#profile-switch`

Comment: Yeah, but if I want to have same id for multiple elements, like div, span it helps me use same id but different properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<label>
Off
<input id="profile-switch-input" type="checkbox" checked="">
<span id="profile-switch-lever" class="lever"></span>
On
</label>
```

CSS

```
.switch label input#profile-switch-input[type="checkbox"]:checked + #profile-switch-lever.lever::after {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Result

[image]

Original

[image]